# How to arrange return order in an idiomatic way using pattern matching in Scala

Tags: scala

```
  def arrange(str1: String, str2: String): (String, String) = {
    if (str1 == "YELLOW") {
      return (str1, str2)
    } else {
      return (str2, str1)
    }
  }
```

I imagine that I could write this using pattern matching in a more idiomatic way

Answer (score 6):

```
   def arrange(str1: String, str2: String) = str1 match {
     case "YELLOW" => str1 -> str2
     case _ => str2 -> str1
   }
```

Comment: Sorry I don't quite get this. What is the `->` doing?

Comment: it's just a fancy way to create a tuple. `str1 -> str2` is the same thing as `(str1, str2)`. This comes handy, for example, when creating a map `Map("foo" -> "bar", "baz" -> "bat")` etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to improve your code.

First off, `if` is an expression, not a statement. (Almost everything in Scala is an expression.) So, you can just `return` the result of the `if` expression instead of `return`ing the individual branch expressions:

```
def arrange(str1: String, str2: String): (String, String) = {
  return if (str1 == "YELLOW") {
    (str1, str2)
  } else {
    (str2, str1)
  }
}
```

Second, the value of the last expression evaluated inside a block, function, or method is the value of the whole block, function, or method, so we can get rid of the `return` altogether:

```
def arrange(str1: String, str2: String): (String, String) = {
  if (str1 == "YELLOW") {
    (str1, str2)
  } else {
    (str2, str1)
  }
}
```

Next, if a block contains only one single expression, then you don't need the block, thus you can get rid of the parentheses. This applies both to the `if` branches:

```
def arrange(str1: String, str2: String): (String, String) = {
  if (str1 == "YELLOW") (str1, str2) else (str2, str1)
}
```

and the method body:

```
def arrange(str1: String, str2: String): (String, String) =
  if (str1 == "YELLOW") (str1, str2) else (str2, str1)
```

Lastly, Scala has return type inference; in general, you don't need to state the return type of a method explicitly. You *can* state it, but it is usually only idiomatic for cases where it isn't obvious.

```
def arrange(str1: String, str2: String) =
  if (str1 == "YELLOW") (str1, str2) else (str2, str1)
```

So, that already looks a whole lot better than your original version, even with purely syntactic changes and without making any semantic changes like switching to pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use pattern match:

```
def arrange(str1: String, str2: String) = str1 match {
  case "YELLOW" => (str1, str2)
  case _ => (str2, str1)
}
```

But for a simple condition like this, an `if` is all we really need. To make the expression in the question "idiomatic", just drop the `return`, given that in Scala, `if` is an expression and not an flow-control statement:

```
def arrange(str1: String, str2: String): (String, String) = 
  if (str1 == "YELLOW") (str1, str2) else (str2, str1)
```

The [principle of least power](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/StrategicScalaStylePrincipleofLeastPower.html) is good guidance:

http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/StrategicScalaStylePrincipleofLeastPower.html